# java mass button colour search

Tags: java, jbutton

so i recently started with java again and i wantedto make a program that has 64 buttons all with individual pictures. Whenever you Left click one it turns blue, when you right click it turns red when you right click it resets THAT SINGLE BUTTON. Here is what i have so far -- can only post two links --

After i got the base of the program all set out i ran into an issue where whenever i middle click i can then re left click to change more than a button a single colour, heres an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQX66.jpg.

Currently the way the clicking works is this:

```
JButton CornerCrimson = new JButton();
    CornerCrimson.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/DG Keys/Corners/Crimson_corner_key.png"));
    CornerCrimson.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent f) {
        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent f) {
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent f) {
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
                if (g1 == 0) {
                    CornerCrimson.setBackground(Color.blue);
                    g1++;
                }

            } else if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                if (g2 == 0) {
                    CornerCrimson.setBackground(Color.red);
                    g2++;
                }
            } else if (SwingUtilities.isMiddleMouseButton(e)) {
                CornerCrimson.setBackground(null);
                g1 = 0;
                g2 = 0;
            }

        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }

    });
```

Here is a pastebin for the full code:http://pastebin.com/31cVkTFY.

Is there a way to make it so i can have this mouse listener apply to ALL the buttons and check to see if im middle mouse clicking on a button with colour?

I was thinking of doing an array but i have no idea on how to do that and still get the buttons having individual pictures like this `JButton CrescentGreen = new JButton();
        CrescentGreen.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/DG Keys/Crescent/Green_crescent_key.png"));
        panel.add(CrescentGreen);`

Any help on sorting out this will be appreciated if this makes no sense feel free to ask below and i will be more precise

TL;DR 64 buttons, mouselistener apply to all, individual colour / check, individual picturess

Thanks for your time

Comment: Make your own MouseListener, not use the anonymous version.

Comment: @Nozdrum  what do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

First create a class, lets call it MyMouseListener

```
public class MyMouseListener extends MouseListener {

    private HowEverYourBaseClassIsCalled myDataObject;

    public MyMouseListener(HowEverYourBaseClassIsCalled myDataObject)
    {
        this.myDataObject = myDataObject;
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent f) {
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent f) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent f) {
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
            if (this.myDataObject.g1 == 0) {
                CornerCrimson.setBackground(Color.blue);
                this.myDataObject.g1++;
            }

        } else if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
            if (this.myDataObject.g2 == 0) {
                CornerCrimson.setBackground(Color.red);
                this.myDataObject.g2++;
            }
        } else if (SwingUtilities.isMiddleMouseButton(e)) {
            CornerCrimson.setBackground(null);
            this.myDataObject.g1 = 0;
            this.myDataObject.g2 = 0;
        }

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

}
```

The HowEverYourBaseClassIsCalled type is wherever you store your g-Values.
Then when you create all your buttons you will just have to add

```
JButton CornerCrimson = new JButton();
CornerCrimson.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/DG Keys/Corners/Crimson_corner_key.png"));
CornerCrimson.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener(this));
```